# Pandas: how to test a result?

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine that you have a simple dataframe as such

```
   low_signal  high_signal  condition  prevision
0         1.2          1.3          1        1.7
1         1.7          1.8          1        1.8
2         1.9          2.0          1        1.9
3         1.6          1.7         -1        1.5
4         1.3          1.4         -1        1.4
```

Now I want to study if my prediction is correct and if so I would like to know the time (which in this case we can say that is equal to the index)

My first condition

```
if df.condition == 1
```

the second is to check if `df.prevision` will ever be lower or equal than the `df.low_signal`.

If that condition is True then the

```
return is the index (in study) of the df.predicted - the index of df.low_signal


   low_signal  high_signal  condition  prevision verification
0         1.2          1.3          1        1.7            1
1         1.7          1.8          1        1.8            1
2         1.9          2.0          1        1.9            0
3         1.6          1.7         -1        1.5            1
4         1.3          1.4         -1        1.4            0
```

That is just for df.condition == 1

For `df.condition == -1` 
is almost the same, however the check is if the `df.prevision will ever be greater or equal than the df.high_signal`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to solve it:

```
In [18]:

df['verification'] = ((df['high_signal'] <= df['prevision']) & (df['condition'] == 1)) \
                     | ((df['low_signal'] <= df['prevision']) & (df['condition'] == -1))

In [19]:

df
Out[19]:
            low_signal  high_signal condition   prevision   verification
0           1.2         1.3         1           1.7         True
1           1.7         1.8         1           1.8         True
2           1.9         2.0         1           1.9         False
3           1.6         1.7         -1          1.5         False
4           1.3         1.4         -1          1.4         True
```

Probably you know that in python True and False correspond to 1 and 0, but if you want to see the `verification` column as int, just do:

```
In [20]:

df['verification'] = df['verification'].astype(int)
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**: I update the answer as per your comments. I don't really understand the 'functional requirement', but anyway if you have a more complex operation you can use pandas' [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

In your case is a bit tricky since:

- you want to access the index inside the `apply` function, and I don't think you can
- you want to iterate over the whole dataframe

But anyway, solving the expression you've put in your comment, you can first add a column with a copy of the index in your dataframe,

```
In [27]:

df['index_cp'] = df.index
```

and then use the apply function,

```
In [28]:

len_df = len(df)
​
def f(x):
    for n in range(len_df):    
        if x.condition == 1 & (x.prevision <= df.low_signal[n]):
            return n - x.index_cp
​
df.apply(f, axis=1)
Out[28]:
0     1
1     1
2     0
3   NaN
4   NaN
dtype: float64
```

Probably you need to modify the function but as I say I did not get the "functional" view and I've just implemented what you've posted. Hope it helps.

Comment: I made a conditional correction in the post... yes it helped however the verification must make a loop search:
for example, for i in range(len(df)):
                           for n in (range(len(df)):
                              if df.condition[i] == 1 & df.prevision[i] <= df.low_signal[n]:
                                    return n - i
In order that the return result is equivalent to time (the difference between those two indices for the first true)

Comment: Ok, then it is much complicated than I thought from your first explanation. I'm updating the answer